# WPF GridViewColumn Cell Visiblity Not Triggering

Tags: wpf, gridview

I am trying to update a cell to be visible when a value is true but it doesn't seem to be updating.

I'm new to WPF so any advice would be appreciated.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Completed">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Completed" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExtractionCompleted}" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it wasn't updating at runtime was because I had not implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. Once this was done the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

Set `TargetName` in your setter

```
   <DataTemplate >
        <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock" Text="Completed" Visibility="Hidden" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExtractionCompleted}" Value="True" >
                <Setter TargetName="myTextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi there, I added this but the text block still doesn't update and become visible if the data is changed at runtime. If I add new data then it is fine, the same as my previous code.